# Convert List of Airport Codes to Entities

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, entity

I have a list of airport codes:

```
airports = {"ABE", "ABI", "ACT"}
```

How can I convert this into a list of entities in Mathematica? Is this possible? I tried:

```
Entity["Airport"] /@ airports
```

but this does not give a correct result.

Thank you for your help! In the end, I need various properties like city, longitude and latitude from those airports.

Any ideas? Help is appreciated!

Regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty close.  The following code should do it:

```
Entity["Airport", #]& /@ airports
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: also `Interpreter["Airport"][airports]`

Answer (score 5):

```
airports = {"ABE", "ABI", "ACT"};

AirportData["Properties"]
```

[image]

```
data = AirportData[#, {"IATACode", "Name", "Cities", "Latitude", 
      "Longitude"}] & /@ airports;

data // Grid
```

[image]

airports = {"ABE", "ABI", "ACT"};

EDIT: A quicker method would be to download a .csv file and filter it.

```
data = Import["http://ourairports.com/data/airports.csv"];
```

The data elements in the file are

```
data[[1]]
```

> {"id", "ident", "type", "name", "latitude_deg", "longitude_deg",
>   "elevation_ft", "continent", "iso_country", "iso_region",
>   "municipality", "scheduled_service", "gps_code", "iata_code",
>   "local_code", "home_link", "wikipedia_link", "keywords"}

Selecting the data elements of interest

```
data2 = data[[All, {14, 4, 11, 10, 5, 6}]];
```

Selecting the airports of interest

```
Select[data2, MemberQ[airports, #[[1]]] &] // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: Great, this is what I am looking for. There remains one issue: my list of airport codes contains 270 elements, which runs super slow. I believe that this is related to the use of entity objects which were introduced in 10.0. Any ideas on that issue? How can I speed up the lookup of properties for many airports? Thank you all, I appreciate your help.

Comment: See edit above using .csv file.

Comment: nice! thank you!